# Watchkit Extension Cannot Read from iCloud

Tags: swift, watchkit, icloud

I am looking for the watchkit extension to read a file from iCloud document storage.  I wrote the file from the iOS app which is also able to read it.  I am leveraging a shared class so the code is the same.  The problem is that on the watch, the URL for the cloud container returns nil.

```
static func readFromFile(fileName:String) -> String?
{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var cloudURL = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)

    cloudURL = cloudURL?.appendingPathComponent("Documents/\(fileName)")

    do
    {
        return try String(contentsOf: cloudURL!)
    } catch {
        print (error)
        return nil
    }
```

In the case above, cloudURL is nil on the watch but not the phone.  For the `forUbiquityContainerIdentifier` I checked that the same identifier is used for both watch and phone.  I have also tried to directly enter the name rather than using nil and letting it grab it from the entitlements.  The format of the container:

```
iCloud.com.company.app
```

It's my understanding that Watch OS 3 is supposed to be able to use iCloud.

Update:

I printed out `let token = fileManager.ubiquityIdentityToken` and I get the following:

> WatchKit Extension[390:687462] [default] [ERROR] error while getting
>   ubiquityIdentityToken: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
>   connection to service named com.apple.bird.token was invalidated."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.bird.token was invalidated.}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have officially heard back from Apple that this is not a supported feature of Watch OS. This runs contrary to their own documentation which I let them know about. Hopefully others see this response and it can save a ton of time that I wound up wasting.

Comment: do you have radar url ?

Answer (score 0):

It was 2021. Apple documentation still says that iCloud Drive methods can be used by watchOS 2.0+, but url forUbiquityContainerIdentifier returns nil :(